# How to configure the maven to use the dependency comming from Eclipse itself

Tags: eclipse, maven

Eclipse comes with some dependencies like Junit. How to configure the maven to use those rather than downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tycho can manage OSGi bundles, that manage their dependencies. For details see the blogpost of [Mattias Holmqvist](http://mattiasholmqvist.se/2010/02/building-with-tycho-part-1-osgi-bundles/). In the third part of these blog posts it is also shown how to use JUnit with Tycho.

However, if you want to you are using Eclipse with standard Java projects, I don't know of any Maven task that reads such information from the Eclipse project and classpath files.